# django 'set' object is not reversible

Tags: django

When I use the passed parameters, I always report an error, but If change this

> { % url

, this error will be gone. please help me solve the problem.

**views.py** is:

```
def mmmm(request):
    return render(request, 'test3.html')

def gettime(request, year, day, month):
    return HttpResponse("time is %s-%s-%s" % (year, month, day))
```

**urls.py** is:

```
app_name = "four"
urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'mmmm', views.mmmm, name='mmmm'),
    re_path(r'gettime/(?P<year>\d+)/(?P<month>\d+)/(?P<day>\d+)/$', views.gettime, name='gettime'),
]
```

test2.html is:

```
<a href="{% url 'mmmm' %}">mmmmm</a><br>
<a href="{% url 'gettime' year=2019 month=12 day=18 %}">cmdb/userinfo/tom/tomnickname/10</a><br>
```

**this error is** :

```
Error during template rendering
In template /Users/jumporange/PycharmProjects/HelloDjango/templates/test2.html, error at line 15

'set' object is not reversible
5   <title>Get student</title>
6   </head>
7   <body>
8   <ul>{% for student in students %}
9       <li>{{ student.s_name }}</li>
10  {% endfor %}
11  </ul>
12  {#<a href="/FOUR/index">mmm</a>#}
13  
14  {#<a href="{% url 'mmmm' %}">mmmmm</a><br>#}
15  <a href="{% url 'gettime' year=2019 month=12 day=18 %}">cmdb/userinfo/tom/tomnickname/10</a><br>
16  </body>
17  </html>
```

Comment: is there reason you need to use re_path instead of path or url ? if you using re_path maybe change the urls.py to `re_path(r'^gettime/(?P<year>\d+)/(?P<month>\d+)/(?P<day>\d+)/$, views.gettime, name='gettime'),` and see if it work, i'm not familiar with re_path much it's only use on regex most of the time

Comment: thanks you for replay，I am modified to do this： `path('gettime/<int:year>/<int:month>/<int:day>', views.gettime, name='gettime')`，still have an error

Comment: had you tried my way if changing the re_path and see if it work ?

Comment: yeah,It does not work

Comment: The error is not in this code. Do you have any other urls.py files? One of them is using `{}` instead of `[]`.